# Set Properties within base function and call function in child function inheritance

Tags: c#, function, inheritance, properties, refactoring

I am trying to refactor some old code and wanted to create more logical inheritance.

We have struct Custom Class which we have separated into (3) levels:

AccountView > Details > Full with inheritance. We set the properties of each one as needed.

After looking at the setters, we wanted to combine them into a single class 'SetAccountProp' with methods that set the properties.

We have the 'CustomerBaseView' where we pass in Models ACCOUNT data which works.

Now for the CustomerDetailView pass the same Model ACCOUNT data, but we would like to fill the properties of 'CustomerBaseView' use function 'CustomerBaseView' then fill the details.

Also, for CustomerFullView pass the Model ACCOUNT data, and fill the properties of 'CustomerBaseView' THEN 'CustomerBaseView' and then the remaining fields for CustomerFullView.

How can I call and fill the 'CustomerBaseView' within the 'CustomerDetailView' function? Do I initialize  new AccountsView(); in each function?

Not sure how to finish up the refactor without repeating the:

```
// -- CustomView  <--- replace with func?
view.Email = data.Email; 
view.Active = data.Active; 
view.FirstName = data.FirstName; 
view.LastName = data.LastName;
```

in the Details and Full functions.

**CODE**

```
namespace BLL.Presenters
{
    public class AccountsView
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details : AccountsView
    {
        public bool Administrator { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Full : Details
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }


    public class SetAccountProp
    {
        public static AccountsView CustomerBaseView(Account data)
        {
            var view = new AccountsView();
            view.Email = data.Email;
            view.Active = data.Active;
            view.FirstName = data.FirstName;
            view.LastName = data.LastName;
            return view;
        }

        public static Details CustomerDetailView(Account data)
        {
            var view = new Details();

            // -- CustomView  <--- replace with func?
            view.Email = data.Email;
            view.Active = data.Active;
            view.FirstName = data.FirstName;
            view.LastName = data.LastName;

            // -- Details
            view.Administrator = data.Administrator;
            view.LastLogin = data.LastLogin;

            return view;
        }

        public static Full CustomerFullView(Account data)
        {
            var view = new Full();

            // -- CustomView <--- replace with func?
            view.Email = data.Email;
            view.Active = data.Active;
            view.FirstName = data.FirstName;
            view.LastName = data.LastName;

            // -- Details <--- replace with func?
            view.Administrator = data.Administrator;
            view.LastLogin = data.LastLogin;

            // -- Full
            view.ID = data.ID;
            view.Created = data.Created;
            view.Modified = data.Modified;
            view.FullName = data.LastName + ", " + data.FirstName;

            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to the rescue! :)

Comment: Is there a reason you have this static class instead of a constructor that can take an Account object? You could chain the constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using constructor chaining, you could have something like this:

Each constructor calls it's base class' constructor first, so you don't have to repeat code.

```
  namespace BLL.Presenters
  {
    using System;

    public class Account // dummy to make it compile
    {
      public string Email;
      public bool Active;
      public string FirstName;
      public string LastName;
      public bool Administrator;
      public DateTime? LastLogin;
      public Guid ID;
      public DateTime Created;
      public DateTime Modified;
    }

    public class AccountsView
    {
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public bool Active { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }

      public AccountsView(Account data)
      {
        this.Email = data.Email;
        this.Active = data.Active;
        this.FirstName = data.FirstName;
        this.LastName = data.LastName;
      }
    }

    public class Details : AccountsView
    {
      public bool Administrator { get; set; }
      public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }

      public Details(Account data) : base(data)
      {
        this.Administrator = data.Administrator;
        this.LastLogin = data.LastLogin;
      }
    }

    public class Full : Details
    {
      public Guid ID { get; set; }
      public DateTime Created { get; set; }
      public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
      public string FullName { get; set; }

      public Full(Account data) : base(data)
      {
        this.ID = data.ID;
        this.Created = data.Created;
        this.Modified = data.Modified;
        this.FullName = data.LastName + ", " + data.FirstName;
      }
    }

    class Program
    {
      static void Main()
      {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I invoke the method as `var newview = new TestAccountsView(data); `  I get an error *Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DAL.Account>' to 'DAL.Account'*

Comment: Then your data is a List, not a single Account. You need to pass just a single Account as parameter.

Comment: Currently I am calling/filling the view as such 

`var data = ctx.Accounts.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName).ToList();`
**return data.Select(CustomView).ToList();**

When I try doing

`return data.Select(TestAccountsView).ToList();`

*Code is unreachable*

Comment: data.Select( d => new TestAccountsView(d) ).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
public class CustomerBase
{
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public bool Active { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    protected void SetAccountInfo(Account account)
    {
        this.Email = account.Email;
        this.Active = account.Active;
        this.FirstName = account.FirstName;
        this.LastName = account.LastName;
    }
}

public class CustomerA : CustomerBase
{
    public string IsAdmin { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; private set; }

    public void SetAccountInfo(Account account)
    {
        base.SetAccountInfo(account);
        this.IsAdmin = account.IsAdmin;
        this.LastLogin = account.LastLogin;
    }

}

 public class Account
{
     //your properties
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

Or let the SetAccountInfo() return `this`

```
public CustomerA SetAccountInfo(Account account)
    {
        base.SetAccountInfo(account);
        this.IsAdmin = account.IsAdmin;
        this.LastLogin = account.LastLogin;
        return this;
    }
```